# Indicates fully charged when not 100%

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I recently (less than 1 month ago) purchased a new Macbook Pro 13". Love it so far, but have a question on the battery. It never reaches 100% - usually it makes it up to 96% then the light on the charger goes from amber to green, and the charging indicator says "fully charged".

I've tried recalibrating the battery as described [here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/9036.html).

Should I just take it to the Apple Store and have someone look at it? Is this a typical behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 17" Macbook Pro battery, is at 95% after 260 cycles!

So this is not normal for such a new battery.

You should go to an Apple Store and probably they will replace it for you!

From [Apple website](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html):

> The built-in battery of your MacBook, MacBook Pro or MacBook Air is designed to deliver up to 1000 full charge and discharge cycles before it reaches 80 percent of its original capacity.

Comment: are you sure? I think the battery does show a 100% indicator but drains out sooner, when its capacity decreases.